# Conditional Merge in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 data sources FirstAPI and SecondAPI:

**FirstAPI**

| appId | policyTypeName | policyTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | Global | null |
| pqrs | null | 1 |
| pqws | Global | null |

**SecondAPI**

| policyTypeName | policyTypeId |
| --- | --- |
| Americas | 1 |
| Global | 2 |

The values are all one-to-one mapping.

**RESULT** : I am trying to add a column to FirstAPI so that it can look like the following:

| appId | policyTypeName | policyTypeId | newCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | Global | null | Global |
| pqrs | null | 1 | Americas |
| pqws | Global | null | Global |

I am trying to write a query in the advanced editor so that I can add `newCol` in FirstAPI. My attempt is to use something similar:

```
if [policyTypeName] = null 
then SecondAPI[policyTypeName] where SecondAPI[policyTypeId]=[policyTypeId]
else [policyTypeName]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSkxKTlFQ0lFyz8lPSswBsfJKc3KUYnWilQoKi4phAiDaECpaXoxNQywA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [appId = _t, policyTypeName = _t, policyTypeId = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"appId", type text}, {"policyTypeName", type text}, {"policyTypeId", Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", (x)=> Table.SelectRows(SecondAPI, (y)=>  if x[policyTypeName] = y[policyTypeName] then true else if   x[policyTypeId] = y[policyTypeId] then true else false  )),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "Custom", {"policyTypeName"}, {"newCol"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```